# How to enable JMX Metrics for Strimzi-Kafka Bridge

Tags: java, jmx, metrics, jconsole, strimzi

I'm enabling JMX port for Strimzi-Kafka bridge by adding these lines in the Kafka-Bridge.sh file.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9250
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9250 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

After this, when I run strimzi and check it in JConsole for the available Metrics, I only get to see basic Java metrics. But no Strimzi specific metrics are available.

[image: JConsole Image for exposed Metrics by Strimzi-Kafka-Bridge application]

Is there a way to enable strimzi specific Metrics? Is there any more configuration required?

Comment: Enable JMX port 9999 as Strimzi supports obtaining JMX metrics from the Kafka brokers.

Comment: even after changing to this:

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999

I'm not seeing anything strimzi specific in JConsole.

Answer (score 1):

The Strimzi HTTP Bridge doesn't support JMX connections. So I do not think you can do that.